# Computer freezes a few moments after startup and wake from sleep (not all the time, but often)

Tags: memory, windows-11, crash, sleep, shutdown

My computer has been freezing a few minutes after start up or wake from sleep, and I have to force shut down and turn it on before my PC will work again. Reliability history shows no error that comes with it. In the most recent crash, I received these errors in Event Viewer:

**1 error right before the crash:**

*HttpEvent*

```
An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint Type=0 Index=0. The error status code is contained within the returned data. (Event 15021)
```

**3 errors immediately after the crash:**

*CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll*

```
SCEP Certificate enrollment initialization for WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-L9IO2IQ$ via https://amd-keyid-578c545f796951421221a4a578acdb5f682f89c8.microsoftaik.azure.net/templates/Aik/scep failed:
```

```
SCEP Certificate enrollment initialization for Local system via https://amd-keyid-578c545f796951421221a4a578acdb5f682f89c8.microsoftaik.azure.net/templates/Aik/scep failed:
```

These 2 errors are very consistent, happening multiple times per day.

*Application Error*

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.22621.1485, time stamp: 0xe7bcd66b
```

The SSL error was very consistent, happening every day my PC was on, sometimes multiple times per day. I wanted to check my ssl certificates, so I did "netsh http show ssl" in administrator cmd, however, it showed me

```
SSL Certificate bindings: 

-------------------------

The configuration registry database is corrupt.
```

I did sfc /scannow and DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, (and /scanhealth) which claimed to fix some corrupt files, but the issue still remains. I also did /chkdisk /f /r, three times, to no avail. I have also done an in-place upgrade of Windows (without resetting personal files/apps)

**Other consistent errors:**

```
The server {8CFC164F-4BE5-4FDD-94E9-E2AF73ED4A19} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

Kernel-PnP warnings are also insanely high in the past 7 days, at 1050, although there has been none in the past 24 hours.

All of it is in the format:

```
The application ___ with process id ___ stopped the removal or ejection for the device ____ 
Process command line: __
List of affected devices:
```

**My system information:**

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-L9IO2IQ
System Manufacturer System manufacturer
System Model    System Product Name
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  SKU
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor, 3400 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 0220, 8/6/2018
SMBIOS Version  3.1
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product   TUF B450M-PLUS GAMING
BaseBoard Version   Rev X.0x
Platform Role   Desktop
Secure Boot State   On
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume5
Locale  United Kingdom
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.22621.1413"
Username    DESKTOP-L9IO2IQ\keiji
Time Zone   Malay Peninsula Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   15.9 GB
Available Physical Memory   5.92 GB
Total Virtual Memory    23.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory    8.78 GB
Page File Space 7.25 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualisation-based security   Not enabled
Windows Defender Application Control policy Enforced
Windows Defender Application Control user mode policy   Off
Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualisation Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

If you need more information, feel free to let me know and I will provide you. If anyone knows how I can fix this, it would be deeply appreciated, as it is giving me a lot of headaches and trouble. Thank you!